# Convert fraction to float in PHP

Tags: php, integer

How to `convert 1/4 to 0.25` in **PHP**.

In form I insert number as `1/4`. In `action page` I get the post variable as `1/4`.
How can I convert this to `0.25`. I think in action page this is obtained as string. Thats why it displayed as `1/4`. But I need `0.25.` How can I do this??

main page

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a">
```

action page

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
echo $a;  //gives 1/4 but need 0.25
```

Please help..

Comment: check my answer, I provided some good ways to solve this issue of yours ;) take a special look at my proposition for your code and a close look at the last version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
<?php

    function calculate_string( $mathString )    {
        $mathString = trim($mathString);
        $mathString = str_replace ('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $mathString); 

        $compute = create_function("", "return (" . $mathString . ");" );
        return 0 + $compute();
    }

    echo calculate_string("1/4");


?>
```

Output:

```
0.25
```

Comment: using `eval()` is usually bad. using `eval()` on user provided data is definitely bad.

Answer (score 1):

one possible way is this:

in action page, first explode the inputed value like:

```
$explode = explode('/', $_POST['a']);
```

then you just divide them :D

```
$result = $explode[0] / $explode[1];
echo $result; //echoes 0.25
```

**L.E:** the best way of doing this in my opinion would be to use 3 inputs. One with the first number, one with the operation and one with the second number. In this case you can make a real calculator and perform normal operations in action page like this:

in display page:

```
<input type="text" name="first_no" id="first_no">
<input type="text" name="operation" id="operation">
<input type="text" name="second_no" id="second_no">
```

in action page:

```
switch($_POST['operation']) {
   case '+';
     $result = $_POST['first_no'] + $_POST['second_no'];
     break;
   case '-';
     $result = $_POST['first_no'] - $_POST['second_no'];
     break;
   case '*';
     $result = $_POST['first_no'] * $_POST['second_no'];
     break;
   case '/';
     $result = $_POST['first_no'] / $_POST['second_no'];
     break;
  //and so on... if you need more
}

echo $result;
```

**L.E2:** Just for fun, I made a version for your code with only 1 input

```
//get index
preg_match("/\D/is", $_POST['a'], $mList, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$index = $mList[0][1];

//get operation
$operation = substr($string, $index, 1);

//get numbers
$explode = explode($operation, $string);

//produce result
switch($operation) {
   case '+';
     $result = $explode[0] + $explode[1];
     break;
   case '-';
     $result = $explode[0] - $explode[1];
     break;
   case '*';
     $result = $explode[0] * $explode[1];
     break;
   case '/';
     $result = $explode[0] / $explode[1];
     break;
  //and so on... if you need more
}

echo $result;
```

hope this helps :D

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use eval here but be carefull! Directly parsing $_POST stuff to eval makes your script extremely dangerous for your webserver if you don't escape the input properly!

If you're sure you will get something like 1/4 or 1/2 this will do it:

```
echo eval("return ".$_POST['a'].";");
```

but as i said. BE CAREFUL WITH THIS
if somebody wants something bad he could just enter `exec('init 0')` into your input and your server will shutdown if your webserver got the permission to do this (this is just one of the countless vulnurabilities to an unsecured eval) so i please you be patient with this.

A second method is splitting your numbers and dividing them. But that will have many format issues for sure.

Greetings